# Inverse Matrix of a sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $\mathbf{A}$ a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $\alpha$ a positive constant.
I want to simplify the following expression:
$$\left(\mathbf{A} + \alpha \, \mathbf{I}\right)^{-1},$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

I looked in the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) to find an identity, but I found only more general formulas like the *Woodbury identity*.
Do you know how to find a simpler identity for this easy case?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** my goal is to obtain an easy expression in terms of products of $\mathbf{I}$, $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ without computing other inversions or decompositions. I can use the same term more times and I don't have to use all of them (I do not want to compute redundant operations).

Comment: You could try looking at it as a geometric series. If you edit the question to tell us what you want to do with this matrix perhaps we can help you find another path to your goal.

Comment: Thanks @EthanBolker, I edited the question.

Comment: Assuming that for you positive definite means symmetric, $A$ is diagonalizable and so one could be reasonably explicit about the form of $({\bf A} + \alpha {\bf I})^{-1}$ in terms of a diagonalization ${\bf A} = {\bf P \Lambda P}^{-1}$.

Comment: @Gio Yes, you're right. I missed that part.

Comment: Yes @Travis, I mean symmetric (now I edited it). Now I try to rethink it in term of diagonalization, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the 'Woodbury identity' or the Sherman-Morrison formula? It expresses your inverse in terms of $A^{-1}$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Nothing wrong, @StubbornAtom. I did not know how to specialised them to obtain the results. Then I found [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243421/simplifying-the-inverse-of-the-sum-of-2-matrices) that helped me. Is it what you suggested?

Comment: As $\bf A$ is positive definite, $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ exists. Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula#Generalization_(Woodbury_Matrix_Identity)), you get  $(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{I})^{-1}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}-\alpha\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{I}+\alpha\mathbf{A}^{-1})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{-1}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom you are right, but this do not solve my problem since I still have to do the inverse of a sum of matrices that it is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You can do the taylor series for $1/(x+\alpha)$ and replace $x$ with $A$ and $\alpha$ with $\alpha \, \mathbf{I}$ . The resulting formula uses only powers of $A$  and $\alpha$, but the sum (Taylor series) is infinite.  It is not possible to do a simple formula without using inversions. Edit: the resulting infinite sum only converges under certain eigenvalue restrictions.  (their absolute value must be less that $\alpha$)

Comment: Let $A=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&2\cr}$. Can you express $(A+aI)^{-1}$ in terms of $I,A,A^{-1},a,a^{-1}$? If not, then that rules out the existence of a formula for the general case.

Comment: $\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
You can express $\ (\mathbf{A}+a\mathbf{I})^{-1}\ $ as a polynomial in $\ \mathbf{A}\ $, derivable from its minimal or characteristic polynomial  $\ p\ $. Under the conditions given  $\ r\eqdef p(−
\alpha)\neq0\ $, and if  $\ q(x)\eqdef\frac{p(x)−r}{x+\alpha}\ $, then $\ (\mathbf{A}+a\mathbf{I})^{-1}=$$\ -r^{-1}q(\mathbf{A})\ $ .  For Gerry Myerson's example, this gives $\ (\mathbf{A}+a\mathbf{I})^{-1}=$$\,
\frac{-1}{(1+a)(2+a)}(\mathbf{A}-(a+3)\mathbf{I})\ $.