# Elementary matrices operations and simplified expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to simplify the following expression between matrices.
Let $\mathbf{A}$ a $n\times n$ symmetric PSD matrix, $\mathbf{I}$ the identity matrix of order $n$ and $\lambda>0$ a positive constant.

I want to simplify the following expression:

$$\mathbf{A} -\mathbf{A} \left[\mathbf{A} + \lambda \mathbf{I}\right]^{-1} \mathbf{A}$$

**My attempt:**
I use the SDV of $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{PDP^T}$. Then as suggested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243421/simplifying-the-inverse-of-the-sum-of-2-matrices),
$$\left[\mathbf{A} + \lambda \mathbf{I}\right]^{-1}=\mathbf{P} \left(\mathbf{D} +\lambda \mathbf{I}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{P^T}.$$

Therefore:

$$\mathbf{A} -\mathbf{A} \left[\mathbf{A} + \lambda \mathbf{I}\right]^{-1} \mathbf{A} =\\
= \mathbf{PDP^T} - \mathbf{PDP^T} \left[\mathbf{P} \left(\mathbf{D} +\lambda \mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{P^T}\right] \mathbf{PDP^T}=\\
=\mathbf{PD}\left[\mathbf{I} -\left( \mathbf{D} + \lambda \mathbf{I} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{D}\right] \mathbf{P^T}=\\
=\mathbf{PD}\left[\mathbf{D}^{-1} -\left( \mathbf{D} + \lambda \mathbf{I} \right)^{-1}\right] \left(\mathbf{PD}\right)^{T}.$$

My questions are:

1. Is it correct?
2. Can the result be simplified further in terms of computational cost?
   I need to use it in an algorithm where the only thing that changes at each step is the value of $\lambda$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your proof, because it looks overly complicated. Anyway, by a change of orthonormal basis, you may assume that $A$ is diagonal and hence the problem reduces to the scalar case. Since $x-\frac{x^2}{x+\lambda}=\frac{\lambda x}{x+\lambda}$, the expression becomes $\lambda A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$, which in your notations is equal to $P\left[\lambda D(D+\lambda I)^{-1}\right]P^T$.